# Which software for conditional probability calculation?

Tags: probability-distributions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculation of a most probable value based on multiple probability distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142665/calculation-of-a-most-probable-value-based-on-multiple-probability-distributions)

We want to solve a problem like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142665/calculation-of-a-most-probable-value-based-on-multiple-probability-distributions):

```
Random Variable: Number of hairs on the head of a person
Probability Distribution 1: Number of hairs depending on gender
Probability Distribution 2: Number of hairs dependent on age
Probability Distribution 3: Number of hairs dependent on hair color

Now I want to calculate the most  expected value for the number 
of hairs for a 34 years old, blonde woman.
```

I have tried to solve the problem with SPSS but I could not. Which software is able to solve such problems?

PS. if you understand the problem and know the name of the software, I would be very grateful for your answer.  Corrections to the question and theoretical controversies are unnecessary.

Comment: *Also, when you do, please be sure to explain what you've tried so far*... Forgot this piece of the advice you received on the other page?

Comment: uh.... as I recall, this is the first redaction of this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142665/calculation-of-a-most-probable-value-based-on-multiple-probability-distributions
i guess it's the same user?

Comment: -1 for "Corrections to the question and theoretical controversies are unnecessary."

Answer (score 0):

R, Stata, MATLAB, and good ol' computation by hand are all capable of performing this calculation.